# Borrar líneas de un archivo que contengan una determinada cadena con un archivo batch (.bat)

Tags: bucle-for, batch, texto

Estoy intentando editar el archivo host para borrar las líneas que contengan #AntiSpam

Para no hacer las pruebas sobre el host directamente he creado otro documento de texto sobre el que hacer las pruebas y lo he llamado **documento.txt**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

0.0.0.0 meetsexpartners13.com #AntiSpam
0.0.0.0 pqdlj.dateszone.net #AntiSpam
0.0.0.0 thebestgame2020.com #AntiSpam
0.0.0.0 hotdatinghookups.com #AntiSpam

## Local by Flywheel - Start ##
::1 testing.local #Local Site
127.0.0.1 testing.local #Local Site
::1 www.testing.local #Local Site
127.0.0.1 www.testing.local #Local Site
## Local by Flywheel - End ##
```

Para esto planteé de hacer una lectura línea por línea del documento de texto:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (documento.txt) DO @ECHO Linea: %%A
pause>nul
```

Y al momento de leer la línea con una condicional comprobar si contiene la cadena **#AntiSpam**

```
@echo off
set linea=0.0.0.0 meetsexpartners13.com #AntiSpam

if "%linea%"=="%linea:#AntiSpam=%" (
    echo No contiene
) else (
    echo Lo contiene
)
pause>nul
```

Pero al momento de unirlos tengo problemas

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (documento.txt) DO (
    set linea=%%A

    if "%linea%"=="%linea:#AntiSpam=%" (echo %%A)
)

pause>nul
```

### Problema

Si bien me parece de que debería funcionar todo bien por alguna razón no puedo guardar la variable **%%A** dentro de **linea**, al menos como lo estoy haciendo se queda en blanco.

Lo hago guardándola porque no puedo hacer directamente sobre **%%A** el **%linea:#AntiSpam=%** o al menos no sé cómo se haría.

### Aviso

Sé que de momento no estoy editando el documento, solo estaría imprimiendo las líneas en consola. Más tarde cuando resuelva esto me pondré con eso, supongo que crearé un archivo temporal sobre el que volcar los datos filtrados y luego de sacar todo remplazaré el contenido de **documento.txt** con el temporal el cual al terminar de pasar borraré.

Aunque si alguien me puede decir una mejor forma que esta que estoy haciendo genial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Linux yo lo haria asi desde la linea de comandos (o lo pones en un bash):

```
cat host | grep -v "#AntiSpam" > nuevo_host
```

**donde:**

- `cat host`: Imprime en la salida el archivo `host`
- `grep -v "#AntiSpam"`:  Si encuentra la cadena `#AntiSpam` se salta la linea y no la muestra, en caso contrario muestra la linea
- `> nuevo_host`: Redirige todo a un nuevo archivo llamado `nuevo_host`

En Windows supongo que debe ser algo asi (no uso ni tengo Windows, no lo puedo probar):

```
type host | findstr /V "#AntiSpam" > nuevo_host
```

Pruebalo y si funciona lo puedes meter en un bat.

Comment: Está bien muchas gracias, en cuanto pueda lo probare haber si funciona.

Comment: Ok, si, ya me diras, gracias.  Creo recordar que el archivo de verdad se llama `hosts` terminado en 's' (al menos en linux)

Comment: Ya lo he probado y funciona a la perfección.
Gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)